# Configuring environment variables for static web site on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to setup a simple static Angular website on S3 per the info:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html

I want to send email via a form that needs to send sendgrid api keys.  Obviously, I want to use environment variables for this to avoid having keys in code.  How do you setup environment variables in S3?

I looked into aws-cli tool but it only shows examples of what appear to be AWS specific enviroment variables.  Is there somewhere in AWS/S3 console were these can be set?

BTW- I would like to use this Angular service which demonstrates the sendgrid service:
https://github.com/onaclovtech/sendgrid/blob/master/sendgrid.js

Comment: You can't set environment variables in S3 but you can in Amazon Lambda. You might consider creating a function in lambda that handles your sendgrid call.

Comment: One approach I had considered (and maybe Lambda would work) but you just pass your sendgrid call to something that will handle that privately, (I wanted to make a service at one point, but sigh, time/life). Sort of like a pass through, so something like sendgrid.blah.com<restofsendgridapi minus keys> then you host your keys and it passes the request through and back... so only one site would be necessary (theoretically) as a passthrough, but you could build all kinds of static sites (thinking similar to say firebase at one point in time).

Comment: maybe AWS Amplify https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/ is the service you need on top of AWS S3

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't set environment variables in S3. S3 is just a static object store, not a dynamic content server. To evaluate variable values would be the very definition of dynamic content, and S3 only serves static content.

Note that AngularJS code runs in the browser, not on a server, so those keys you want to keep out of your code are going to be viewable in the browser by anyone that knows how to look. There's no way for you to hide those values if you want to call SendGrid from a client-side framework.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way for hiding keys via S3.  I thought since they had a how-to on static hosting a web site they must have some way since who really hosts a truely static site?  Everyone needs to accept email.

Comment: Exactly my same question. found out https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/ may be the answer.

Comment: There is a way. Front your site with Cloudfront and use CloudFront functions to use the newly introduced key/value pair.

Not the best solution and may not fit your use case but I wanted to add that this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the reputed email marketing companies won't even allow calling their services from a front-end where the keys could be exposed such as MailChimp. You can read the [below](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#authentication):

> Note: MailChimp does not support the client-side implementation of our API using CORS requests due to the potential security risk of exposing account API keys.

Now, it may happen that many a time, you would want to still use environment variables to separate environments and such (non-sensitive information). In such scenarios, you should use the environment variables on your machine and generate builds with the help of webpack or some other build tool.