# Securely manage configuration data for a React app hosted in S3 behind a Cloudfront Distribution

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

**Setup**

- React - v16.6.3
- S3 Bucket - configured for Static Website Hosting
- CloudFront Distribution - with the aforementioned S3 bucket as the origin
- Cognito - to manage user access
- SSM Parameter store - to manage configuration data and secrets

**Problem**

We use an `awsConfig.js` file to handle the configuration information the React app needs to communicate with the AWS Cognito service.

```js
export default {
  cognito: {
    REGION: xxxx,
    USER_POOL_ID: xxxx_xxxx,
    APP_CLIENT_ID: xxxx,
    IDENTITY_POOL_ID: xxxx
  }
};
```

Using this file means we have exposed some configuration information in the browser which we would like to avoid.

**What I've tried so far**

Using the AWS SSM Parameter Store to hold these values, and then reference them in the `awsConfig.js` file as environment variables.  However I've run into the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226645/configuring-environment-variables-for-static-web-site-on-aws-s3) - Because the app is statically hosted, you can't call content dynamically.

**Questions**

1. How can I securely call configuration data for a React app hosted this way?
2. Is it necessary to obfuscate this type of configuration data?

Comment: Any reason why you’re not using lambda?

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you elaborate on how I would use lambda to achieve this please?

Comment: Sorry I meant why aren’t you using lambda for your app since that has environment variable support which what you are looking for.