# How to deploy React app from Github to AWS S3 bucket with environment variables set Note: I didn't push .env files in github

Tags: reactjs, github, amazon-s3, continuous-deployment

Hi React experts(especially with CI/CD knowledge),

Please read it carefully and provide some possible way.

> Background:
>
> - I have created a react app using 'create-react-app'
> - command  I have created 3 .env files for different environments like .env.development,.env.staging and .env.production.
> - For security reasons, we should not push those .env files to public Github repo
> - I have taken the necessary steps with the .gitignore file

Now I want to deploy my code from Github directly to AWS S3 bucket with those env variables set.
***How does one go about doing this?***

Note: I have not pushed my .env files in Github.bSo, my Github repo doesn't contain those .env files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring environment variables for static web site on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36226645/configuring-environment-variables-for-static-web-site-on-aws-s3)

Answer (score 4):

According to [here](https://newbedev.com/configuring-environment-variables-for-static-web-site-on-aws-s3). We can't set environment variables in S3. S3 is just a static object store, not a dynamic content server.

According to [react documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) all the environment variables in the runtime are set to final build (inside build folder) after executing `npm run build`. when building React app all the secret variables in the `.env` file are in the runtime environment and after finishing `npm run build` those environment variables(secret variables) are added to the build folder (final app).

Because S3 is not a runtime environment we need to build a react app and upload the `build` folder to the S3 bucket after creating a bucket or we can provide that environment variables using GitHub action.